# (Pandas Dataframe) How do I permute or combine rows and columns to a new attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, flatten

for example, I have a table like this:

```
    a  b
e   20 30
d   60 50
f   120 10
```

my desired result is:

```
    a_e  a_d a_f b_e b_d b_f
1   20   60  120 30  50  10
```

I tried redo the crosstab and pivot table, but it doesn't work.

Comment: shouldn't it be? be `a_e  a_d  a_f  b_e b_d b_f`

Comment: yes! that's a typo. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and [`flatten`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.Index.flatten.html) to convert it to your desired format

##### Creating data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [20,60,120], 'b':[30,50,10]}, index = ['e', 'd', 'f'])
```

##### Generating output

```
pd.DataFrame([df.T.values.flatten()], columns = [f"{col}_{ind}" for col in df.columns for ind in df.index])
```

##### Output

This gives us the expected output

```
  a_e a_d  a_f b_e b_d b_f
0  20  60  120  30  50  10
```

Comment: @user17270513 glad, I could help you